# How can I add the current date or time to end of each line in file?

Tags: date, sed, append

I have a file called `data.txt`.

I want to add the current date, or time, or both to the beginning or end of each line.

I have tried this:

```
awk -v v1=$var ' { printf("%s,%s\n", $0, v1) } ' data.txt > data.txt
```

I have tried this:

```
sed "s/$/,$var/" data.txt
```

Nothing works.

Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about :

```
cat filename | sed "s/$/ `date`/"
```

Comment: Or use `cat filename | sed "s/^/\`date\` /"` to add a timestamp to the **beginning** of each line.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this

```
awk -v v1=$var ' { printf("%s,%s\n", $0, v1) } ' data.txt > data.txt
```

is that the `>` redirection happens **first**, and the shell truncates the file. Only then does the shell exec awk, which then reads an empty file.

Choose one of these:

```
sed -i "s/\$/ $var/" data.txt

awk -v "date=$var" '{print $0, date}' data.txt > tmpfile && mv tmpfile data.txt
```

**However**, does your `$var` contain slashes (such as "10/04/2011 12:34") ?  If yes, then choose a different delimiter for sed's `s///` command: `sed -i "s@\$@ $var@" data.txt`

Comment: Good one, I guess you can even use `awk -v date="$(date)" '$0=$0date' file`.